# Swift - How to check if element with certain properties exists in an array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

In my NookController I have the following:

```
    var nooks = [NookController(name:"Library",coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D(),availability:.Empty, hours: "Open 24 hours"),
            NookController(name:"Math Building",coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D(),availability:.Empty, hours: "Open 24 hours")]
```

In my ViewController, I created the following function to verify whether the new "Nook" I'm appending is a duplicate or not:

```
func checkDuplicates() -> Bool {
        if nooks.contains(NookController(name:"Library",coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D(),availability:.Empty,hours:"Open 24 hours")) {
            return true
        }
        else {
            return false
    }
}
```

However, I'm testing this and it is not working when I in fact add an element to the array that already exists in this array (it always returns false).

Comment: you create a different element with the same properties, that's why it always returns false

Comment: The pointer in your array and the pointer you are comparing are different. It will always return false. Instead you should compare unique Id if there's one.

Answer (score 0):

Override the equals operator for your NookController class:

```
func == (left: NookController, right: NookController) -> Bool {
    return left.name == right.name
}
```

Then use it as such:

```
func checkDuplicates() -> Bool {
    let nook = NookController(name:"Library",coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D(),availability:.Empty,hours:"Open 24 hours")
    return nooks.contains(nook)
}
```

Comment: The `==` operator should compare all properties of the class, not just one. And if you implement `==` you should also implement `hash`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define what "the same" means for a Nook - Is it the same coordinate?  The same name?  Both? The same hours as well?

Once you have this then you need to make your `NookController` conform to the `Equatable` protocol and implement the `==` function.  For example:

```
extension NookController: Equatable {
     static func ==(lhs: NookController, rhs: NookController) -> Bool {

        if lhs.name == rhs.name &&
            lhs.location.latitude == rhs.location.latitude &&
            lhs.location.longitude == rhs.location.longitude {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}

var nooks = [NookController(name: "Library", location: CLLocationCoordinate2D(), availability: .Empty, hours: "24 hours"),
         NookController(name: "Math Building", location: CLLocationCoordinate2D(), availability: .Empty, hours: "24 hours")
]

let testNook = NookController(name: "Library", location: CLLocationCoordinate2D(), availability: .Empty, hours: "24 hours")

print(nooks.contains(testNook))  // Prints true
```

Although, as @Ryan suggests, you should probably have a uniqueID for each nook (you would certainly want this if you are going to persist the data in some sort of data store) and use that to test equality.

You class should also conform to  `Hashable`.  This will allow it to be used in sets (useful for eliminating duplicates) and be used as a dictionary key:

```
extension NookController: Hashable {
    var hashValue: Int {
        return self.name.hash ^ Int(self.location.latitude) ^ Int(self.location.longitude)
    }
}
```